# If a false vacuum decays in the universe, would it necessarily create an inflating bubble?

Tags: cosmology, universe, vacuum, cosmological-inflation

this is my first question in this website!

So, I read that if the universe suffered a vacuum decay from a false vacuum state it could create a bubble travelling at lightspeed.
Would this bubble nucleation necessarily occur if that happened? Or it could NOT happen?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_vacuum

Comment: Vacuum decay is basically synonymous with "bubble of true vacuum forms, and conquers the universe". The bubble spreads because it is at lower energy and everything it touches, relaxes into the lower-energy state of the fundamental fields that it has made possible. So I interpret your question to mean, could a bubble of new vacuum form, and behave in some other way - could it vanish right away, could it just sit there, could it be walled off behind an event horizon...

Comment: Tentatively, my answer is maybe, but that these scenarios might require an unlikely balance of energies between old and new vacua. Hopefully someone can come up with a good answer.

Answer (score -2):

According to relativity and quantum physics to create that so called bubble would be to manipulate the very fabric of space-time. This bubble theory is called Alcubierre drive. To create the bubble you need to contract space and that comes from an alternate force. In simplified terms, you would need another object to go fast enough to balance out the force on the opposite side of it (thanks Newton!) and the front creating a bubble around it. So no, the vaccum alone could not cause a bubble to form and the additional force is a factor that helps the bubble form and then be able to reach light speed.

Comment: That is a completely different topic. The bubble in vacuum decay forms spontaneously. See Astrid's link